# send response to a client from a server

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

I want to send a response to a client after he is connected

Here is the snippet of the code

```
try {

    while (true)

    {
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();

        byte[] reception = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = in.read(reception);

        String bufferServer = "Buffer Server ";
        baos.write(reception, 0, read);
        reception = baos.toByteArray();
        String chaine = new String(reception, "Cp1252");
        System.out.println("Reception from client : " + chaine);

        byte[] bufferServeurToClient = bufferServer.getBytes();
        out.write(bufferServeurToClient); // send to client
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

The clients can send multiple request , that ' s why i use a while(true) in order to listen requests until client disconnect.

The problem is that i receive nothing from the server in the client side.
If i remove the while(true) it works and i receive the variable "bufferServeurToClient" at client side

edit: Client side which work now , but when i print the response , i have a lot of  weird character(square) after my string , why?

```
String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost ().getHostAddress ();
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        System.out.println("SOCKET = " + socket);

         InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(out);
    String bufferClient="Buffer Client ";

    byte[] bufferClientToServer= bufferClient.getBytes();
    out.write(bufferClientToServer);

    byte[] reception = new byte[1024] ;          

    int read;

    while ((read = bis.read(reception)) != -1){
        String chaine = new String( reception , "Cp1252" );
        System.out.println("Reception from server: " + chaine);


    }
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
```

}

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where does the program block when you run it in the debugger line-by-line?

Comment: @Philipp  It blocks at " int read =in.read(reception);"

Answer (score 3):

> The clients can send multiple request, that's why I use a while(true) in order to listen requests until client disconnect.

If the client can send multiple requests, you'll need a way of differentiating between them - *and* between the responses. Currently, you're just assuming that a single call to `read` will do the job:

```
int read =in.read(reception);
```

That could read *part* of a request, or potentially multiple requests. Common options to fix this are to use some sort of delimiter (e.g. one request per text line) or to use length-prefixing, where (say) the first four bytes of each request or response say how much more data there is.

Now you haven't shown what your client side looks like at all - but my guess is that you're actually waiting for the server to close the connection, which of course you'll never do while the `while(true)` loop is there. So that's another piece of code you'll need to modify.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your reply. Currently , i already manage client connected by thread(one thread by client). But indeed i don t differenciate request(thought the read variable will changes at each request). Currently the server side closes the connection after the client finishes his work. I can't show the client code because it's confidential(the client is finished , i only have trouble from the server side )

Comment: @user799698: I don't see how you can think that the client code is finished before you've got it working with the server side code. You'll almost certainly need to change both in order to get things working robustly - length-prefixing both the requests and the responses would probably be the simplest approach. Note that you don't have to show the *real* client code - just client code which exhibits the same problem. A short but complete program (both sides) demonstrating the problem would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but i don ' t have control on the client side because it is an application that I have not done, which was already developped by another since longtime. I can only send requests from a jsp page(i don t have any idea on the code behind). My job consists to refine the server side with new specification. I will try to develop a client test by the way

Comment: Ok , i don t have the client side code , but i manage to create a simple client (without multiple request because i don t know how to do that) which represent the same problem as before(ie not receiving response from server). Thank you

Comment: @user799698: If you can't change the client code, you're fundamentally broken. You have no way of telling when you've received the whole of a client request. You need to fix the protocol first.

Comment: Thank you very much , i will send a request to my manager about the client side(in order to change it) , when i clearly identify the problem with my client sample

Answer (score 1):

Its worth nothing that if you send multiple requests they are likely to be read as a single request.   This is because stream don't have a concept of messages so if you write many bytes they can be read in any manner. e.g. one byte at a time, or all at once.

In any case you should get at least one reply.

Comment: Thank you for your help , but it's the main problem because i don 't receiver anything! When i debbug it , it blocks at  "int read =in.read(reception);" but i can still syso the read value. So i don t understand why nothing is send.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense because the first time the loop runs is exactly the same as running the loop once. A `while` loop won't change the way a socket behaves. I would ensure there is nothing important happening after the while loop and post how you are reading from the socket.

Comment: Thank you but I already tried several times. With the while(true). The client remains connected but receive nothing. If i take off the loop , the client do one request , receive the response from the server , then he disconnects automatically

Comment: In that case I suspect the problem is on the client side. It isn't reading the data until the server disconnects. e.g. BufferedReader.readLine() would do this. Try using `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)` instead of `while(true)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the server never disconnects , he always keep running. I tried your solution. It works with for(int i=0;i<1;i++), i receive the datas , but when i try for(int i=0;i<2;i++) it don t work >_< i don t understand nothing.

Comment: I suspect that when you loop more than once, the read() blocks and the server doesn't disconnect so the client doesn't return because it is waiting for a disconnect.

Comment: You are right, because when i try to force close the server , then i receive the response in client side. I updated my code with client side sample

Comment: `while((read = in.read(reception)) > 0)` this will repeat until the end of the stream is reached. As you only print the response after the end of file has been reached, you won't see anything until this happens.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading until EOS at the client before you print anything, and the server is never closing the connection, so there is no EOS.

You don't need all these ByteArrayOutputStreams. Have a good look at your code and you will see they can be completely eliminated. This will also solve the EOS problem.

The server should close the socket if read() returns -1.

Comment: Thank you very much , i udpated my code thanks to your advice to read datas until i detect -1

Comment: @user799698 But that's what you were already doing. The problem was the lack of output until you found it.

Comment: so i need to add "bos.write(reception,0,read);" in my while loop ? And do u know why i have weird character(square) when i print the server answer? (i think it s because the byte array is not full filled, so it full himself with weird character)Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial document : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html
this might help you